# Remove element/s from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I remove a item/s from an `Array` in JavaScript ?

```
function restructureChatBoxes() {
    align = 0;
    for (x in chatBoxes) {
        chatboxtitle = chatBoxes[x];

        if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display') != 'none') {
            if (align == 0) {
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('right', '20px');
            } else {
                width = (align)*(225+7)+20;
                $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('right', width+'px');
            }
            align++;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to remove the Chatbox when its closed from the List.

```
function closeChatBox(chatboxtitle) {
//HERE THE REMOVE FROM LIST ? 
    $('#chatbox_'+chatboxtitle).css('display','none');
    restructureChatBoxes();

    $.post("chat.php?action=closechat", { chatbox: chatboxtitle} , function(data){  
    });

}
```

Thanks for all Answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: No cause its a bit more special

Answer (score 1):

First, find the `index` of the element you want to remove:

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);
```

Note: [*browser support for indexOf*](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf) is limited, it is not supported in IE7-8.

Then remove it with [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The second parameter of `splice` is the number of elements to remove. Note, `splice` modifies the array in place and returns a new array containing the elements that have been removed.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-specific-element-from-an-array/5767357#5767357)

Comment: You copied [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-specific-element-from-an-array#answer-5767357) without any modification and without any reference to it. Post a link in a comment if you don't want to answer the question yourself.

Comment: Hey thanks :) 
But i only have the Chatboxtitle ... 
How can i handle it now ?:O

Comment: I have already marked this question as duplicate and why to invent the new wheel every time when information is already available round.

Comment: He only pointed me the correct way ? 
and i guess thats what count or ?
Nobody is searching whole stack answers ...

Comment: You don't get the point. You sold another one's answer as yours. How would you call that? And no, you didn't mark the question as duplicate. What about that?

Comment: I flagged it as duplicate, may be it did not get approved. and I putted as reference too.